# Hiding and showing UITableview with slide down and slide up animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

is it possible to put animation to UITableView?

I currently have this:

```
- (IBAction)mPesoAccount:(id)sender {
    if (accountBalanceTableView.isHidden) {
        accountBalanceTableView.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        accountBalanceTableView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

it hides or show the uitableview whenever i click a button, i would like to add an animation when i'm hiding and showing the uitableview

it would similar like a dropdown item, where it slides up into the button and collapses down when the button clicked again.

Comment: can you add the UI for which type you expect

Comment: @Anbu.karthik i can't understand your question.

Comment: are you using constraints?

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou when yow want to collapses  tableview reduce the height  UIView animate and if you want to expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply animating your `UITableView` frame if you are using non constraints approach, or making the bottom constraint IBOutlet and changing the constant value

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubViews
    {
          [super viewDidLayoutSubViews];
          self.originalTableViewFrame = accountBalanceTableView.frame;
    }

    - (IBAction)mPesoAccount:(id)sender {

        if (accountBalanceTableView.isHidden)
        {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
                accountBalanceTableView.frame = self.originalTableViewFrame;

            }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 accountBalanceTableView.hidden = NO;
                             }];

        }
        else
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                accountBalanceTableView.frame = CGRectMake(originalTableViewFrame.origin.x, originalTableViewFrame.origin.y + originalTableViewFrame.size.height, originalTableViewFrame.size.width, 0);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                accountBalanceTableView.hidden = YES;
            }];
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like this animation is similar to fade rather than sliding up/down. Thanks for trying but this is not what i'm  looking for.

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou is sliding from bottom part of your view? are you using constraints?

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou You should mention that in your question

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou what would you like? Slide up or down? are you using constraints?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it would similar like a dropdown item, where it slides up into the button and collapses down when the button clicked again. i dont use any constraints in height because i need a dynamic height.

Comment: What/where is originalFrame? i'm sorry im new to iOs development.

Comment: That is the frame that should have your UITableView in the expanded state can be any @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou

Comment: This works, but the animation when it collapsing/sliding down is not showing , only slides up animation is visible.

Comment: You want slide down and collapsing animation? @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou

Comment: Yes, exactly what i need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170776/discussion-between-freelancsandroidlovesyou-and-reinier-melian).

Comment: ok @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou i will test this example and post my findings